# Install Firefox on Windows 7 for all users

Tags: windows-7, firefox

This has got to be among the simplest possible things in the word *for those who know how to do it.* However, **I don't**, and I have been astonished to find nothing about it from google searches other than unanswered copies of the exact same question.

All I want is Firefox, and I want it for all users on a Windows 7 laptop.  In fact, the real story is that I want it to work *again* for all users after updating from Firefox 5 to Firefox 8, which process has apparently left it unavailable to anybody but the administrator.

I'll probably find the answer to this in the time it takes for this question to get answered, but I promise I'll upvote you anyway :-)  I mainly wanted to get this question (hopefully with good answers) out there so that it turns up on a Google search.

Comment: If/when you come up with your own answer, come add it as an answer. Have you tried completely removing and reinstalling Firefox? Maybe something weird happened during the upgrade?

Comment: So to clarify: 5 was installed for all users but a subsequent upgrade to 8 caused it to only be available to administrators?

Comment: I believe that I misinterpreted the problem. The actual issue is that for users other than my admin account, the ".EXE" file association is hosed, and I can't find any non-slimeball tool to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this is a red herring. My actual problem is a broken .EXE file association (the possibility of which blows my mind and further cements my conviction that Windows is a deeply, deeply flawed architecture that really should never ever be used by anybody for anything under any circumstances).